# Bash on Windows. Баг или фича?

Tags: windows, bash

В домашней директории пользователя сделал симлинк на папку в корне диска C виндов (`C:\Experimental`). Когда я перемещаюсь туда, то могу просматривать содержимое каталогов. Но при попытке зайти в подкаталоги (даже создаваемые мной из баша) их имя приписывается к приглашению, `pwd` так же растет, но, судя по содержимому, я сижу в том же самом `Experimental`. Могу так "углубляться" бесконечно.

Судя по `ls -l`, права `777`, но будто бы это не так. Без использования симлинка все работает как надо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ах, нет, не ссылка. Каталог. Хм, на баг похоже, действительно.

Comment: Ах, да, а что за файл там лежит? `ls -l bash` ?

Comment: @0andriy скрипт, но это не имеет значения, т.к. воспроизводится для всех поддиректорий, в том числе для новосозданных.